# Extract character from string in R vector separated by symbol

Tags: r, regex, string

Hi I have a vector of string in R which are separated by @ , I want to extract words separated by @..Example

```
tweets =c( " @john @tom it is wonderful ", "@neel it is awesome ", "it is awesome")
```

I want a matrix/data.frame of  names only with no text like this as output

```
X1=c("john","tom') 
X2 =c("neel",NA) , x3 = (NA,NA), data frame = as.data.frame(X1,X2,x3)
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

A `base R` option would be to extract using `gregexpr/regmatches` and then pad `NA`s to the `list` elements with `length<-` and convert to a `matrix`

```
lst <- regmatches(tweets, gregexpr("(?<=@)\\w+", tweets, perl = TRUE))
do.call(rbind, lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst))))
#     [,1]   [,2] 
#[1,] "john" "tom"
#[2,] "neel" NA   
#[3,] NA     NA
```